# ¿Qué me recomiendan para manejar grandes cantidades de datos?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, datatables

He desarrollado un sistema usando PHP, MySql, PDO, DataTables y hasta ahora ha sido bueno.

El inconveniente es que necesito manejar tablas con grandes cantidades de registro en un futuro. o sea, al principio serian pocos datos, posiblemente se tenga que manejar grandes cantidades de registros tanto agrega.

He estado poblando Ajax y Json, el rollo es que al cargar la data no me permite el manejo de DataTables, como por ejemplo ordenar las columnas y otras características.

Gracias...

Igualmente, cualquier sugerencia y orientación, agradecería.

El código que he usado sin problemas.

SCRIPT

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        responsive: true,
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'copyHtml5',
            'excelHtml5',
            'csvHtml5',
            'pdfHtml5'
        ]
    } );
} );
</script>
```

PHP (en el mismo archivo)

```
<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered display" width="100%">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Cedula</th>
    <th>Apellido</th>
    <th>Nombre</th>
    <th>Telefono</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php
$stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM table_1")->fetchAll();
foreach ($stmt as $row) {
?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['col_5'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['col_6'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['col_8'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['col_10'] ?></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
</tbody>
<tfoot>
<tr>
    <th>Cedula</th>
    <th>Apellido</th>
    <th>Nombre</th>
    <th>Telefono</th>
</tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
```

El código que me da problemas.

SCRIPT

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        "ajax": {
            url : "get_DataTables.php",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "JSON",
            },
        responsive: true,
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'copyHtml5',
            'excelHtml5',
            'csvHtml5',
            'pdfHtml5'
        ]
    } );
} );
```

PHP (en otro archivo)

```
<?php
$con = new mysqli("localhost","root","","data_prueba");
$data_array = array();
$sql = "select * from table_1";
$query = $con->query($sql);
while($data = $query->fetch_object()){
    $data_array[] = array(
    $data->col_5,
    $data->col_6,
    $data->col_8,
    $data->col_10
    );
}
$new_array  = array("data"=>$data_array);
echo json_encode($new_array);
?>
```

Comment: Datatables deberia funcionar bien, solo que no es responsive,  o al menos no lo he manejado a fondo ni me he metido tanto como para saber si tiene o no un diseño responsive integrado, lo que yo te recomiendo es la misma solucion que propone mysql para manejar grandes cantidades de columnas, que adecues tu tabla para que tenga un scroll horizontal, de esta manera si el contenido no cabe en la pantalla puedas igual verlo scroleando.

Comment: Si tu pregunta es sobre directamente ya el manejo de la informacion, lo que tienes que hacer es un sistema de paginación, el cual te vaya cargando informacion por trozos, en vez de cargar TODA la informacion de golpe, basicamente haz de cuenta que es como si cortaras un pedazo de queso, se lo expusieras a la gente y conforme la gente pida mas vas cortando y mostrando mas trozos de queso, un ejemplo muy comun en las paginas es que consultes los primeros 60 registros por ejemplo, y los dividas en paginas de 20 registros cada una, cuando el usuario cambie a una pagina siguiente

Comment: Cargas otros 60 registros mas apartir del registro anterior, y listo, solo asegurate de no ir sobreescribiendo información si no mas bien de ir pegando informacion, de esta manera puedes llegar a cargar mas de 1000 registros de manera eficienten sin que te suponga un problema, eso si, esto es buena idea si no haras uso de filtros en el `datatable`, de lo contrario si hay muchos registros ya cargados en el datatable mientras mas sean mas tardara el datatable en poder mostrarte la informacion filtrada.

Comment: Si esperas tener grandes cargas y cantidades de datos en tu aplicación, muy probablemente hayas buscado hosting web. Si esperas tener una aplicación a gran escala que maneje cantidades de datos enormes, es muy recomendable que uses una infraestructura en la nube, puedes optar por GCP, Azure o AWS. Todas están respaldadas por Google, Microsoft y Amazon respectivamente. Y están optimizadas para ofrecer disponibilidad en tu aplicación incluso cuando la carga es masiva.

Comment: Veo que envías contenido al cliente en forma de un HTML, esto puede dificultar la etiquetación de datos y extracción precisa una vez obtenida del lado del servidor. ¿Has considerado unificar tus archivos PHP en un solo archivo que los junte todos para armar una _API REST_ y devolver el contenido que necesitan en JSON y no en HTML? De esta manera, puedes usar únicamente el método `JSON.parse()` del lado del cliente.

Comment: Hola, gracias por las respuestas.

Con relación a mostrar los datos, Datables me da esa opción. El mayor problema es la carga de la información, es lenta y apenas la plataforma está en fase de desarrollo, se estima manejar grandes cantidades de registro (Puede ser en una sola tabla o varias)

Comment: Ten en cuenta que la velocidad de carga de datos depende de la carga actual del sistema y de los recursos disponibles principalmente. SI aún asi estás experimentando una carga muy lenta de los datos, es posible que necesites evaluar la complejidad de tu base de datos  y los datos que recibes. Basado en mi experiencia, creo que sería totalmente mejor servir el contenido como JSON en vez de HTML, porque al ser JSON, el cliente no tiene que hacer tanto proceso para interpretarlo, si el cliente interpreta el contenido HTMl, esto puede ser lento, ineficiente e impreciso.

Comment: Por eso te recomendé que en vez de servir contenido HTML al cliente, consideres enviarlo en JSON, de esta manera los datos ya estarán etiquetados y el cliente no tendrá que gastar más recursos en interpretarlos. Si no es una necesidad que sirvas el contenido en HTML, puedes optar por usar la función [`json_encode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) de PHP para convertir el contenido de la BD a un JSON, pero ten cuidado de no compartir información sensible y de asegurar que solo peticiones autorizadas accedan a la información.

Comment: Manda los datos como JSON no como HTML, así JS podrá trabajar con ellos.